# How to change the remote url username?

Tags: git

I got a VM from a colleague and want to adapt the repo link (which you paste in when you initially clone the repo) to hold my username.

Example: currenlty the links looks something like this:

`https://USERNAME_TO_CHANGE@git.johannes.net/cool.git`

Comment: You can't directly change the username because it points the authorized user for clone the git repository.If you want to change username you have to create the different user on git.

Comment: See the linked duplicate, and/or consider running `git config --edit` (but make sure your chosen editor does not mangle text files by turning LF-only line endings into CR-LF line endings).